# How to turn off automatic typing correction in Lion?

Tags: macos

Since upgrading to Lion I notice that typing is automatically getting "corrected".

For example, I type "I posted to elance that" and the word elance automatically changes to "glance".  I back up and change the 'g' to an 'e' and it changes it back to "glance" again.

I first noticed it in Mail, but I see it's also happening here in Safari too.

How do I turn this off?  Note: I don't mind the 'red-squiggle' when it thinks there's a typo, but I don't want it automatically changing my text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User "Gauzy" posted this in a comment.  I'm posting it here and marking it as the correct answer:

For Safari (or any other app with a text input box, for the most part) right click (or control click) the text area, goto Spelling and Grammar, and deselect Correct Spelling Automatically. Screenshot – Gauzy

Answer (score 9):

Go to system preferences -> and then language/text

Hit the "Text" tab.

There is a checkbox that says "Correct spelling automatically". Uncheck it.

Look here for more info:

http://www.applegazette.com/mac/how-to-disable-auto-correct-in-os-x-lion/

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work because it looks like TextEdit and Safari have their own "correct spelling automatically" options that are enabled.  Is there no way to change this globally?  Also, I do like when it warns me of the bad typing with the red squiggle.  It would be nice if I could have that without the annoying automatic changes.

Comment: For TextEdit go to the top bar and click TextEdit -> Preferences. At the bottom is a checkbox that says "Correct spelling automatically" uncheck that. For Safari I have no idea. Hope that helps!

Comment: For Safari (or any other app with a text input box, for the most part) right click (or control click) the text area, goto Spelling and Grammar, and deselect Correct Spelling Automatically. [Screenshot](http://cl.ly/8nx9)

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal window, and run this:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSAutomaticSpellingCorrectionEnabled -bool NO
```

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer not to fiddle at the command line.  If it's not in a UI somewhere it scares me. :)

Comment: For both Chris and my solution, make sure you're completely closing and relaunching safari and textedit before testing.

Comment: The setting in System Preferences changes the same key in ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist.